# get error No module named 'cryptography' when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, cryptography, pyinstaller

I try to convert py to exe with pyinstall but get this error please help
I dont know why this code can run in SV Code

1011.py

```
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def keyy():
    password1 = 'test'
    password2 = password1.encode()
    salt = b'\x18\xa0V\xcc\2\xddZ\xd6\xb6\xbf\xb0\xcecq\x30eZ'
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm = hashes.SHA256(), length = 32, salt = salt, iterations = 100000, backend = default_backend())
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password2))

def Encrypt(text):
    key = keyy()
    encoded = text.encode()
    f = Fernet(key)
    return f.encrypt(encoded)

a = input()
print(Encrypt(a))
```

terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1011.py", line 2, in <module>
.uleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
[3408] Failed to execute script 1011
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fix it I try to install PyInstaller to my Conda then its work

.

**PyTutorials (Youtube Chanel)** said:

> By any chance, did you install PyInstaller in one installation of
> Python and cryptography in a different installation of Python
> accidentally? If so, PyInstaller can't see cryptography when
> packaging.